# How can I structure existing bookmarks when merging PDFs with Ghostscript?

Tags: merge, ghostscript, bookmarks

For a publication I need to merge individual article PDFs which have existing bookmarks (outlines).

I can do that successfully with Ghostscript:

```
gswin32.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=o.pdf a.pdf b.pdf
```

But the resulting file shows the bookmarks of the input files concatenated. What I need instead is a top-level bookmark with each input PDF's title and its bookmark tree below that.

Can I achieve this with Ghostscript?

I've tried using pdfmarks, but this option seems to be reserved for creating the entire tree from scratch.

Thank you!

Comment: No, you cannot easily do this with Ghostscript's pdfwrite device. You would have to strip the outlines from the source files (so that they don't interfere) and manually build the entire outline tree for the final output file using pdfmarks. Please note; Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not merge PDF files, the output PDF file (obviously in this case) has nothing in common, internally, with the input files.

Comment: Thank you @KenS. My existing solution does a similar thing with pdftk. I had hoped to replace it with a smarter solution that does not need a license. (cpdf can do it but is $$ for commercial use).